# Creating an alphanumeric sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, sequence

I want to create a sequence that generates values like:

```
A00000000
A00000001
..
..
..
A99999999
B00000000
B00000001
..
..
```

It should be generated with the initial alphabetic character A and once it reaches A99999999 it should changed to B and so on.

A normal sequence in Oracle won't give the alphanumeric sequence. How can I generate sequential values in this pattern?

Comment: this answer might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943146/creating-oracle-sequence-that-starts-with-alphanumeric

Comment: What does the 'random' in the title refer to?

Comment: random means as sequence to be generated in that format

Comment: @Loci..In that question, there is a constant word 'INV' but in my case it should genearetd with the alphabets A and once reached 99..it should changed to B and son

Comment: @Arun Only integer valued sequences can be created.

Answer (score 5):

You have to create 1 sequence and 1 transforming function:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE num_seq
START WITH 6500000000
INCREMENT BY 1
MAXVALUE 9099999999;

FUNCTION next_id(seq_name) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  x VARCHAR2(28);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT TRIM(TO_CHAR(' || seq_name || '.NextVal)) FROM dual' INTO x;
  RETURN CHR(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(x, 1, 2))) || SUBSTR(x, 3);
END;
```

The function generates ids from `A00000000` to `Z99999999` when called with `next_id('num_seq')`. The trick is the `CHR(ascii_code)` function, which returns the characters on positions 65-90, that is A-Z.

**Edited:**
Function made more general - you can pass any sequence as parameter and you can simply add/remove digits in the START WITH and MAXVALUE clause of the SEQUENCE definition, without a need of changing the function.

Comment: Thanks Pavel :) Its working and i will modify the sequence as per my request

Comment: Is there anyway once it reaches Z99999999, I need to start the next search from AA0000000, AA0000001.....like so on.. @Pavel

Comment: @arun yes, it is possible with 1 seq. You have to calculate the range starts and then take the corresponding range, subtract the start and translate the value. E.g. r0~a00000000=0, r1~aa0000000=2600000000, r2~aaa000000=2600000000+26*26*10^7, r(i)=r(i-1)+26^i*10^(9-i)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a numeric sequence but convert the first two characters to a hex value on the fly. If you create your sequence as:

```
create sequence s42 start with 1000000000 maxvalue 1599999999;
```

... then have a function to simplify, though you don't strictly need it:

```
create function alpha_seq return varchar2 as
begin
  return to_char(trunc(s42.nextval / 100000000), 'FMXX')
    || substr(to_char(s42.currval, 'FM0000000000'), 3);
end;
/
```

The sequence value is always 10 digits. The first two are pulled off and converted to their hex equivalent, and then the rest are appended.

As a demo:

```
select alpha_seq from dual
connect by level < 5;

ALPHA_SEQ
----------
A00000000 
A00000001 
A00000002 
A00000003 

-- skip a load of numbers
alter sequence s42 increment by 99999994;
select alpha_seq from dual;

ALPHA_SEQ
----------
A99999997 

alter sequence s42 increment by 1;

select alpha_seq from dual
connect by level < 5;

ALPHA_SEQ
----------
A99999998 
A99999999 
B00000000 
B00000001 

-- skip a load of numbers
alter sequence s42 increment by 99999996;
select alpha_seq from dual;

ALPHA_SEQ
----------
B99999997 

alter sequence s42 increment by 1;

select alpha_seq from dual
connect by level < 5;

ALPHA_SEQ
----------
B99999998 
B99999999 
C00000000 
C00000001
```

The max value on the sequence means it will go up to F99999999, and then error if you call nextval again. I'm assuming the first digit is supposed to be hexadecimal; if you want A-Z then you can make the sequence start as 6500000000 and convert the first two digits to a character with `chr()` instead as 65 is converted to A, etc.

Comment: Is there anyway once it reaches Z99999999, I need to start the next search from AA0000000, AA0000001.....like so on..

Comment: @Arun - just for the first two digits, or then AAA... etc. once those are exhausted? Changing the behaviour of each digit from 0-9 to 0-Z isn't going to be simple. It would be easier to go 19, 1A, ... 1F, 20, ... 29, 2A, ... i.e. in base 36.

Comment: Whether this can be done by using the existing sequence itself?

Answer (score -3):

```
function generate_universal_id(pid){
    let BASE_VALUE = 100000000;
    let prefix = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
    let prefix_index = pid/100000;
    let intvalue = Math.floor( prefix_index );
    prefix = prefix[intvalue];
    BASE_VALUE = BASE_VALUE + pid;
    BASE_VALUE = BASE_VALUE.toString().slice(-5);

    if(pid == 100000 || pid == 200000 || pid == 300000 || pid == 400000 || pid == 500000 || pid == 600000 || pid == 700000 || pid == 800000 || pid == 900000 ){
        BASE_VALUE = BASE_VALUE + 1;
    }
    BASE_VALUE = BASE_VALUE.toString().slice(-5)
    let universal_id = `${prefix}${BASE_VALUE}`
    console.log(universal_id);
}

generate_universal_id(100000)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Your question so far is quite unclear as it does not actually contain any description of what it is you are trying to achieve, what problems you are encountering and are trying to solve. In case you have a problem and need help, the best thing to do is to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In case you believe that the code is doing what you want but you would like to hear people comment on it and possible improve, you could consider posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In which language is your function written? It certainly doesn't look sql-ish.